# How to Convert mlt xml file to a melt script

Tags: mlt

I have an mlt xml file and I want to convert it to a melt script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<mlt>
    <profile description="DV/DVD NTSC" display_aspect_den="3" display_aspect_num="4" frame_rate_den="1001" frame_rate_num="30000" height="480" progressive="0" sample_aspect_den="9" sample_aspect_num="8" width="720"/>
    <tractor id="tractor0">
        <multitrack>
            <playlist id="Background Track">
                <producer id="90845eaa-7e94-11e6-8271-d8cb8ae1b41a" in="0" length="1164" novdpau="1" out="1163">
                    <property name="mlt_service">color</property>
                </producer>
            </playlist>
            <playlist id="Track 1">
                <producer id="481e211e-7e94-11e6-8271-d8cb8ae1b41a" in="0" length="1154" novdpau="1" out="1153">
                    <property name="resource">/home/mahi/Desktop/Short Video Resume.mp4</property>
                </producer>
            </playlist>
            <playlist id="Track 2">
                <blank length="10.0"/>
                <producer id="4e16767a-7e94-11e6-8271-d8cb8ae1b41a" in="0" length="130" novdpau="1" out="129">
                    <property name="resource">/home/mahi/Desktop/output/mov/intro.mov</property>
                </producer>
                <blank length="14.0"/>
                <producer id="523cf170-7e94-11e6-8271-d8cb8ae1b41a" in="0" length="110" novdpau="1" out="109">
                    <property name="resource">/home/mahi/Desktop/output/mov/name_title.mov</property>
                </producer>
                <blank length="74.0"/>
                <producer id="4bbfdf06-7e94-11e6-8271-d8cb8ae1b41a" in="0" length="238" novdpau="1" out="237">
                    <property name="resource">/home/mahi/Desktop/output/mov/4 items.mov</property>
                </producer>
                <blank length="43.0"/>
                <producer id="56440a06-7e94-11e6-8271-d8cb8ae1b41a" in="0" length="118" novdpau="1" out="117">
                    <property name="resource">/home/mahi/Desktop/output/mov/head_title.mov</property>
                </producer>
                <blank length="50.0"/>
                <producer id="57ed29aa-7e94-11e6-8271-d8cb8ae1b41a" in="0" length="179" novdpau="1" out="178">
                    <property name="resource">/home/mahi/Desktop/output/mov/3 items.mov</property>
                </producer>
                <blank length="65.0"/>
                <producer id="50bf816e-7e94-11e6-8271-d8cb8ae1b41a" in="0" length="130" novdpau="1" out="129">
                    <property name="resource">/home/mahi/Desktop/output/mov/outro.mov</property>
                </producer>
            </playlist>
        </multitrack>
        <filter gain="1" in="0" mlt_service="volume" out="1153" track="1"/>
        <transition in="0" out="1153">
            <property name="mlt_service">composite</property>
            <property name="a_track">0</property>
            <property name="b_track">1</property>
            <property name="progressive">1</property>
            <property name="geometry">0=0%,0%:100%x100%:100; -1=0%,0%:100%x100%:100; </property>
            <property name="halign">centre</property>
            <property name="valign">centre</property>
            <property name="distort">0</property>
            <property name="fill">1</property>
        </transition>
        <transition in="0" out="1153">
            <property name="mlt_service">mix</property>
            <property name="a_track">0</property>
            <property name="b_track">1</property>
            <property name="combine">1</property>
            <property name="always_active">1</property>
        </transition>
        <filter gain="1" in="10" mlt_service="volume" out="139" track="2"/>
        <transition in="10" out="139">
            <property name="mlt_service">composite</property>
            <property name="a_track">0</property>
            <property name="b_track">2</property>
            <property name="progressive">1</property>
            <property name="geometry">0=0%,0%:100%x100%:100; -1=0%,0%:100%x100%:100; </property>
            <property name="halign">centre</property>
            <property name="valign">centre</property>
            <property name="distort">0</property>
            <property name="fill">1</property>
        </transition>
        <transition in="10" out="139">
            <property name="mlt_service">mix</property>
            <property name="a_track">0</property>
            <property name="b_track">2</property>
            <property name="combine">1</property>
            <property name="always_active">1</property>
        </transition>
        <filter gain="1" in="154" mlt_service="volume" out="263" track="2"/>
        <transition in="154" out="263">
            <property name="mlt_service">composite</property>
            <property name="a_track">0</property>
            <property name="b_track">2</property>
            <property name="progressive">1</property>
            <property name="geometry">0=0%,0%:100%x100%:100; -1=0%,0%:100%x100%:100; </property>
            <property name="halign">centre</property>
            <property name="valign">centre</property>
            <property name="distort">0</property>
            <property name="fill">1</property>
        </transition>
        <transition in="154" out="263">
            <property name="mlt_service">mix</property>
            <property name="a_track">0</property>
            <property name="b_track">2</property>
            <property name="combine">1</property>
            <property name="always_active">1</property>
        </transition>
        <filter gain="1" in="338" mlt_service="volume" out="575" track="2"/>
        <transition in="338" out="575">
            <property name="mlt_service">composite</property>
            <property name="a_track">0</property>
            <property name="b_track">2</property>
            <property name="progressive">1</property>
            <property name="geometry">0=0%,0%:100%x100%:100; -1=0%,0%:100%x100%:100; </property>
            <property name="halign">centre</property>
            <property name="valign">centre</property>
            <property name="distort">0</property>
            <property name="fill">1</property>
        </transition>
        <transition in="338" out="575">
            <property name="mlt_service">mix</property>
            <property name="a_track">0</property>
            <property name="b_track">2</property>
            <property name="combine">1</property>
            <property name="always_active">1</property>
        </transition>
        <filter gain="1" in="619" mlt_service="volume" out="736" track="2"/>
        <transition in="619" out="736">
            <property name="mlt_service">composite</property>
            <property name="a_track">0</property>
            <property name="b_track">2</property>
            <property name="progressive">1</property>
            <property name="geometry">0=0%,0%:100%x100%:100; -1=0%,0%:100%x100%:100; </property>
            <property name="halign">centre</property>
            <property name="valign">centre</property>
            <property name="distort">0</property>
            <property name="fill">1</property>
        </transition>
        <transition in="619" out="736">
            <property name="mlt_service">mix</property>
            <property name="a_track">0</property>
            <property name="b_track">2</property>
            <property name="combine">1</property>
            <property name="always_active">1</property>
        </transition>
        <filter gain="1" in="787" mlt_service="volume" out="965" track="2"/>
        <transition in="787" out="965">
            <property name="mlt_service">composite</property>
            <property name="a_track">0</property>
            <property name="b_track">2</property>
            <property name="progressive">1</property>
            <property name="geometry">0=0%,0%:100%x100%:100; -1=0%,0%:100%x100%:100; </property>
            <property name="halign">centre</property>
            <property name="valign">centre</property>
            <property name="distort">0</property>
            <property name="fill">1</property>
        </transition>
        <transition in="787" out="965">
            <property name="mlt_service">mix</property>
            <property name="a_track">0</property>
            <property name="b_track">2</property>
            <property name="combine">1</property>
            <property name="always_active">1</property>
        </transition>
        <filter gain="1" in="1031" mlt_service="volume" out="1160" track="2"/>
        <transition in="1031" out="1160">
            <property name="mlt_service">composite</property>
            <property name="a_track">0</property>
            <property name="b_track">2</property>
            <property name="progressive">1</property>
            <property name="geometry">0=0%,0%:100%x100%:100; -1=0%,0%:100%x100%:100; </property>
            <property name="halign">centre</property>
            <property name="valign">centre</property>
            <property name="distort">0</property>
            <property name="fill">1</property>
        </transition>
        <transition in="1031" out="1160">
            <property name="mlt_service">mix</property>
            <property name="a_track">0</property>
            <property name="b_track">2</property>
            <property name="combine">1</property>
            <property name="always_active">1</property>
        </transition>
    </tractor>
</mlt>
```

The melt script I have written is not giving the same output as the above XML file.

melt -track Short\ Video\ Resume.mp4 -track intro.mov in=0 out=129 name_title.mov in=0 out=109 outro.mov in=0 out=129

Comment: Why not simply run `melt mlt.xml`? It is quite some work to convert that to melt command line syntax.

Comment: @DanDennedy I want to do this programmatically, which is why I wanted to generate the a script.

Comment: Why? Imagine there is no extensive command line syntax and melt is simply a XML processor. In any case I cannot help you any further.